# SFTP file transfer using Retrofit2.0

Tags: android, retrofit, sftp

Is Retrofit provides us functionality to upload files on SFTP server can any one give any example

Comment: Hi please correct question as well of it is wrong and solution as well for the same

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit is a library that turns your **HTTP API** into a Java interface. It's not for any FTP purpose. but you can use this library for uploading files using **Multipart Requests** for example :

```
private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {  
// create upload service client
FileUploadService service =
        ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

// https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
// use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

// create RequestBody instance from file
RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(
                     MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                     file
         );

// MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
MultipartBody.Part body =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

// add another part within the multipart request
String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
RequestBody description =
        RequestBody.create(
                okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

// finally, execute the request
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                           Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Log.v("Upload", "success");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

}

Comment: ok but i have SFTP server where i have to provide username and password before connecting to server where i should do that in above code i have a alternative of JCraft library JSH but i want to know weather can we do it with Retrofit

Comment: No you can't use retrofit ... use alternatives like https://github.com/jonghough/AndroidSSH @VishalMokal